# design a layout like below image with image buttons in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

[image]

Hi,

I want to design the buttons like the image above. eight button in a circular way. I am confusing how to design them in a circular to cricket logo.

I have tried it using relative layout and linear layout but can not make like this.

Please help me to make this view possible to implement.

Comment: You will have to programatically calculate the CenterX and CenterY for each of the image and then place those images at these points.

Comment: @rushabh can u share ur experience about it , I am trying to do the same thing but stuck , my application crashed when i launch it on emulator

Comment: I have customize the code that Grishu gave below and my code is working properly.

Comment: @RushabhPatel thanks for the reply , Can you share your code ? I am stuck on it .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out the [Wheel Component](http://developer.digitalaria.com/devguide/gama/en/gama/wheel_android.php) which shows the circular views with the scrolling layout.
You can also download the reference demo [HERE](http://developer.digitalaria.com/res/fdownload.php?f=gama_sample_wheel_android.zip).

**EDITED:**
Check out other similar demo [HERE](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/780) and [HERE](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/946)